# FInd a US street address in text (preferably using Python regex)

Tags: python, regex, postal-code

Disclaimer: I read very carefully this thread:
[Street Address search in a string - Python or Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542941/street-address-search-in-a-string-python-or-ruby)
and many other resources.

Nothing works for me so far.

In some more details here is what I am looking for is:

The rules are relaxed and I definitely am not asking for a perfect code that covers all cases; just a few simple basic ones with assumptions that the address should be in the format:

> a) Street number (1...N digits);
>
> b) Street name : one or more words capitalized;
>
> b-2) (optional) would be best if it could be prefixed with abbrev. "S.", "N.", "E.", "W."
>
> c) (optional) unit/apartment/etc can be any (incl. empty) number of arbitrary characters
>
> d) Street "type": one of ("st.", "ave.", "way");
>
> e) City name : 1 or more Capitalized words;
>
> f) (optional) state abbreviation (2 letters)
>
> g) (optional) zip which is any 5 digits.

None of the above needs to be a valid thing (e.g. an existing city or zip).

I am trying expressions like these so far:

> > > pat = re.compile(r'\d{1,4}( \w+){1,5}, (.*), ( \w+){1,5}, (AZ|CA|CO|NH), [0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?', re.IGNORECASE)

```
>>> pat.search("123 East Virginia avenue, unit 123, San Ramondo, CA, 94444")
```

Don't work, and for me it's not easy to understand why. Specifically: how do I separate in my pattern a group of any words from one of specific words that should follow, like state abbrev. or street "type ("st., ave.)?

Anyhow: here is an example of what I am hoping to get:
Given
    def ex_addr(text):
        # does the re magic
        # returns 1st address (all addresses?) or None if nothing found

```
for t in [
'The meeting will be held at 22 West Westin st., South Carolina, 12345 on Nov.-18',
'The meeting will be held at 22 West Westin street, SC, 12345 on Nov.-18',

'Hi there,\n How about meeting tomorr. @10am-sh in Chadds @ 123 S. Vancouver ave. in Ottawa? \nThanks!!!',
'Hi there,\n How about meeting tomorr. @10am-sh in Chadds @ 123 S. Vancouver avenue in Ottawa? \nThanks!!!',

'This was written in 1999 in Montreal',

"Cool cafe at 420 Funny Lane, Cupertino CA is way too cool",

"We're at a party at 12321 Mammoth Lane, Lexington MA 77777; Come have a beer!"
] print ex_addr(t)
```

I would like to get:

> ```
> '22 West Westin st., South Carolina, 12345'
> '22 West Westin street, SC, 12345'
> '123 S. Vancouver ave. in Ottawa'
> '123 S. Vancouver avenue in Ottawa'
> None # for 'This was written in 1999 in Montreal',
> "420 Funny Lane, Cupertino CA",
> "12321 Mammoth Lane, Lexington MA 77777"
> ```

Could you  please help?

Comment: take a look at PLY for something like this maybe ... I doubt a regex will be good enough

Comment: Thanks Joran, I need to consider PLY. Seems like yet steeper curve that creating rules for nltk.ne_chunk, but who knows:-). Thanks in any case!  BTW: why exactly regex wouldn't be good enough? I don't need more than 90% recall.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d{1,4}( \w+){1,5}, (.*), ( \w+){1,5}, (AZ|CA|CO|NH), [0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?
```

In this regex, you have one too many spaces (before `( \w+){1,5}`, which already begins with one). Removing it, it matches your example.

I don't think you can assume that a "unit 123" or similar will be there, or there might be several ones (e.g. "building A, apt 3"). Note that in your initial regex, the `.` might match `,` which could lead to very long (and unwanted) matches.
You should probably accept several such groups with a limitation on the number (e.g. replace `, (.*)` with something like `(, [^,]{1,20}){0,5}`.

In any case, you will probably never get something 100% accurate that will accept any variation people might throw at them. Do lots of tests! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @remram! I'm just learning regex....:-). Here is how my current one looks: any comments? - 
    `>>> pat = re.compile(r'\d{1,7}( \w+){1,6} (st|street|ave|avenue|ln|lane), (apt|unit|apartment)[\., ]+.*[\. ,]+(AZ|CA|CO|NH)[\. ,]\d{5}')`

Comment: I'm not sure what the `[\., ]+` part is for, and be careful as the `.*` part can potentially eat up a lot of text.

Answer (score 11):

I just ran across this in GitHub as I am having a similar problem.  Appears to work and be more robust than your current solution.

https://github.com/madisonmay/CommonRegex

Looking at the code, the regex for street address accounts for many more scenarios.  '\d{1,4} [\w\s]{1,20}(?:street|st|avenue|ave|road|rd|highway|hwy|square|sq|trail|trl|drive|dr|court|ct|parkway|pkwy|circle|cir|boulevard|blvd)\W?(?=\s|$)'